# How to activate selection mode when editing form in design mode in VIsual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

Every time I click a control (button, textbox), a new border is added. I can't select the controls on my form now. What I'm looking for is a command to activate the selection mode but I can't find it anywhere on the Toolbox pane or on any toolbars. Please help.

Comment: What editor are you in? VS or Blend?

Comment: VS - it is implied in my tags I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'Select' tool which has the icon of the black mouse pointer